# how to use TyrGet pattern with default value to get everything done in one line

Tags: c#, .net

let's say we have the following code which is the most standard code to achieve the purpose:

```
// iterate each key value pairs in a Dictionary

string value;
if (!kvp.TryGetValue("MyKey", out value))
   value= "default";
```

but I want to do everything in one line, which is:

```
string newValue = kvp.TryGetValue("MyKey", out string value) ? value : "default";

// `value` is null if the key is not found, newValue is "default" which I can use
// but I don't want to use a new string variable `newValue`,
// I want "default" to be assigned to `value` variable
```

I also don't want to use any `if` statement such as:

```
if(!kvp.TryGetValue("MyKey", out string value)) value = "default" ;
// it is two statement technically
```

there is another workaround as:

```
string value = kvp.TryGetValue("MyKey", out value) ? value : "default";

// compiler translates the above statement into
string value;
if (!kvp.TryGetValue("MyKey", out value))
   value= "default";
```

but it is not very readable, how can you assign `value` to `value` itself if you just look at it in the first sight without thinking how compiler kicks in

I can write a wrapper function to take the key as parameter but I feel that there must be another way to do it.

and I acknowledge that there is a `GetValueOrDefault` like `kvp.GetValueOrDefault("MyKey", "default")`
but what I really want to do is

```
kvp.TryGetValue("MyKey", out string value) ? value : value = "default";  // code doesn't compile, you get the idea which is
```

so is it a way to do everything in one line?

Comment: I'm not convinced by your explanation of why your one-line approach is problematic. Why is not using `value` a problem? Also, "is it an elegant way" is opinion based, and is not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Sweeper, because it want the default value to be "default", instead of null, so in my one-line approach, the default is `null`

Comment: I mean why do you care so much about having to use `value` instead of `newValue`? Why does this matter?

Comment: Just combine your first example with the second example, declaring the string `value` on the left side of the assignment and using it as an `out` parameter to the method (where you don't need to declare the type for the out parameter since it's already been defined): `string value = kvp.TryGetValue("MyKey", out value) ? value : "default";`. See the answer from @NineBerry below.

Comment: @RufusL it works, only a minor thing, it is internally converted as `string value; if (!kvp.TryGetValue("MyKey", out value)) value= "default";`. And `string value = kvp.TryGetValue("MyKey", out value) ? value : "default";` is not very readable, you will be like: how can you assign value to value itself then you realize it is a compiler thing

Comment: That has nothing to do with your question as stated, and I see values assigned to themselves fairly regularly (at least enough that it doesn't cause alarm). It's really hard to understand what your objective is here. You asked for a one liner where you didn't have to declare a separate variable, and now you're concerned with compiler-generated code? Seems like some details may be missing from your question if that doesn't answer it.

Answer (score 5):

You can declare the `value` variable as a result of the ternary expression:

```
string value = kvp.TryGetValue("MyKey", out value) ? value :  "default";
```

Other possibilities:

---

You can use this syntax

```
if(!kvp.TryGetValue("MyKey", out string value)) value = "default" ;
```

When the result of `TryGetValue` is false, assign the default value.

---

When available (in .net Core 2 and higher), you can also use the `GetValueOrDefault` extension method:

```
string value = kvp.GetValueOrDefault("MyKey", "default");
```

---

Or write that extension method yourself:

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static T2 GetValueOrDefault<T1, T2>(IDictionary<T1, T2> dict, T1 key, T2 defaultValue)
    {
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out T2 value)) value = defaultValue;
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own extension to get default value. Not sure why `kvp` if you can use dictionary...

```cs
public static bool TryGetValueOrDefault(this IDictionary<string, string> d, string key, string def, out string v)
{
    if (d.ContainsKey(key))
    {    
        v = d[key];
        return true;
    }

    v = def;
    return false;
}


. . . . . 
if (myDict.TryGetValueOrDefault("key", "someDefVal", out string retVal))
{
     // do something for found value
}
else
{
    // do something when value is not found
}


DoSomethingWithYourValue(retVal);
```

Or just forget about `Try` part and do

```cs
public static string GetDictValueOrDefault(this IDictionary<string, string> d, string key, string def).....

var ret = GetDictValueOrDefault("key", "someDefVal")
DoSomethingWithYourValue(ret);
```